# How does vp argument in gridExtra::tableGrob works?

Tags: r, gridextra

How does vp argument in gridExtra::tableGrob works? Documentation only states `vp: optional viewport` and i couldn't find a vignette that does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A viewport is a fundamental part of the `grid` graphics system, which allows the user to specify a rectangular portion of the plotting window to draw on as if it were a normal plotting window with normal co-ordinates. This allows us to draw shapes, plots and tables, then scale and rotate them by specifying viewport dimensions. You can read more about viewports by typing `?grid::viewport` into your console.

The `vp` argument of `tableGrob` allows you to pre-specify a viewport in which to draw the `tableGrob`. Here's a very simple (and a bit silly) example.

First, we'll load our packages and define some reproducible dummy data:

```r
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(Month = month.name, 
                 Value = scales::dollar(runif(12, 1e5, 2e5)))
```

And we can make a `tableGrob` like this:

```
tg1 <- tableGrob(df)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg1)
```

[image]

Now let's do the same thing with a rotated viewport passed to `vp`:

```
tg2 <- tableGrob(df, vp = viewport(angle = 45))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>